# How to add instruction to VersionedTransaction

Tags: solana-program, python

I have the following:

```
raw_tx = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(b64decode(transaction_data))
signature = keypair.sign_message(to_bytes_versioned(raw_tx.message))
signed_tx = VersionedTransaction.populate(raw_tx.message, [signature])
```

And I would like to add an instruction of type solders.instruction.Instruction.

I tried this:

```
account_keys = raw_transaction.message.account_keys
length_account_keys = len(account_keys)

account_keys.append(instruction.program_id)

new_instruction = CompiledInstruction(
    program_id_index=length_account_keys,
    data=instruction.data,
    accounts=instruction.accounts,
)
length_account_keys = len(account_keys)

raw_instructions.append(new_instruction)

new_message = Message.new_with_compiled_instructions(
    num_required_signatures=raw_transaction.message.header.num_required_signatures,
    num_readonly_signed_accounts=raw_transaction.message.header.num_readonly_signed_accounts,
    num_readonly_unsigned_accounts=raw_transaction.message.header.num_readonly_unsigned_accounts,
    account_keys=account_keys,
    recent_blockhash=raw_transaction.message.recent_blockhash,
    instructions=raw_instructions,
)

signature = keypair.sign_message(to_bytes_versioned(new_message))

signed_tx = VersionedTransaction.populate(new_message, [signature])

trx = await async_client.send_transaction(
    signed_tx,
    opts=TxOpts(skip_confirmation=False, preflight_commitment=Confirmed)
)
```

But I get an error in new_instruction = CompiledInstruction(

> TypeError: argument 'accounts': 'list' object cannot be converted to
> 'PyBytes'

And if I do

```
new_instruction = CompiledInstruction(
            program_id_index=length_account_keys,
            data=instruction.data,
            accounts=raw_instructions[0].accounts,
        )
```

I get another error with     trx = await async_client.send_transaction(

> RPCNoResultException: invalid transaction: Transaction failed to
> sanitize accounts offsets correctly

Any idea please?